# Really simple Java code not working

Tags: java, variables

I am an absolute beginner to programming and I've started with java. I wrote this code and I just don't know what's wrong with it.

```
public class multiples3and5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int mult3 = 0; mult3 < 1000; mult3 += 3);
            System.out.println(mult3);
    }
}
```

I keep getting this error on my terminal:

```
multiples3and5.java:7: error: cannot find symbol

System.out.println(mult3);
                   ^
symbol:   variable mult3
location: class multiples3and5

1 error
```

Comment: You need to get rid of the semicokon at the end of the `for` line

Comment: Try removing semicolon at the end of you `for`statement and put instead a `{`

Comment: How do i format my code http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 1):

You didn't start your code block properly. At the end of the `for` loop declaration, you put a semicolon instead of an opening curly bracket `{`. Without code, this just looped through and removed the `mult3` variable from the scope, because it was declared for the loop.

This is the fix:

```
public class multiples3and5 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        for(int mult3 = 0; mult3 < 1000; mult3 += 3){
            System.out.println(mult3);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ya this worked, thanks man. I'm still getting to grips with it. Do you know how i could find the sum of all the multiples of 3 (between 0 and 1000)?That's what I'm ultimately trying to do.

Comment: @Physco111 Just use your code but create some other variable (outside of loop), add `mult3` to it every iteration and then print it out after the loop.

Answer (score 1):

It is simply because you are using a semicolon after for loop..The semicolon will end the for loop execution and since your variable mult3 is outside this for loop the declaration is not known to Sopln statement

Remove semicolon

```
 for (int mult3 = 0; mult3 < 1000; mult3 += 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your line no 5 is wrong.
Try like this..

```
for (int mult3 = 0; mult3 < 1000; mult3 += 3)
```

Remove the last semi-colon.If you put it your mult3 is local and not accessible out of the scope.

if you want to find the sum of your multiples of 3(as stated in the comments)
it is very simple.
Declare a variable,initialize it to 0 and the add your loop variable at each iteration.

```
int sum=0;
for (int mult3 = 0; mult3 < 1000; mult3 += 3)
{
  sum+=mult3;
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

And that is it.

Comment: can I ask why the += is necessary in java? in both the for loop

Comment: and the the 'sum+=mult3;' wh

Comment: Because if you do 'mult3+3' you are just adding 3 to mult3 and not assigning your variable with a new calculated value.  mult3+=3 is just like 'mult3=mult3+3' see both are different.